# Implementing metropolis algorithm in C

Tags: performance, beginner, c, multithreading, pthreads

This is my second C program (an improved version of the [first one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/245907/224270)). I want to optimize this simulation.

**Algorithm**
The simulation algorithm is:

1. The system can go from \$i\$ to \$i+1\$ with probability \$e^{-L\theta(\rho_i)}\$, where \$\rho_i=i/L\$, and \$\theta(\rho)=\rho(2b-\rho)\$.
2. When system reaches \$n=0\$, it is reset to a position based on how much time it spent on some \$n>0\$.
3. At the end we are intrested in knowing \$\langle\rho\rangle=\sum_{t}\rho_t\$.

**Code**
Following is the code. I believe this code can be compactified also. I do not understand the norms of the ANSI C standard. Feel free to correct me anywhere.

1. I also do not understand if I am properly using random numbers or not!.
2. I am limited by the number of Monte-Carlo steps. With my code, I cannot go beyond `sweeps > ULONG_MAX`. Can this be improved?
3. The program is slower than the equivalent python program I wrote! I tried to learn C so that I can write optimised code! And it seems that I am not successful in that yet. Will learning C++ and write code in that would help?
4. Is `<pthread.h>` a good library?

````
/*
Monte Carlo Simulation for calculating QSD (or Quasi-Stationary distribution) for the forwarded random walk.

complie using "gcc filename.c -lm -lpthread"
run using "./a.out 0.5"

Author: Kartik
Date: July 23
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h> 
#include<limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define LATTICE_SIZE 10
#define N_SWEEPS 10000000
#define PRECISION 1/1000000.
#define CPUs 10
#define RAND (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX

double rho[LATTICE_SIZE];
double initial;
FILE *fp;


struct simulation_parameters{
    int n;
    unsigned long long sweep;
    unsigned long long distribution[LATTICE_SIZE];
    double forward_rate[LATTICE_SIZE];
    double rho_t, rho_tminus;
};

void calculate_forward_rates(double *forward_rate, double b)
{
    int i;
    double theta;
    for(i = 0; i < LATTICE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        theta = rho[i] * (2 * b - rho[i]);
        forward_rate[i] = exp(-LATTICE_SIZE * theta);
    }
    return;
}


//Following function activate when the system gets absorbed
int activate(unsigned long long *distribution, unsigned long long norm)
{
    int n;
    double cumsum = 0.0, u_rand = RAND;
    for(n = 0; cumsum <= u_rand; n++)
        cumsum += (double)distribution[n]/(double)norm;
    return n - 1;
}


double calculate_avg_density(unsigned long long *distribution, unsigned long long norm)
{
    int i;
    double avg_density = 0.0;
    for (i=0; i<LATTICE_SIZE; i++)
        avg_density += (rho[i]*distribution[i])/norm;
    return avg_density;
}

void *monte_carlo_sweeps(void *vargp)
{
    int i;
    double *beta = (double *)vargp;
    struct simulation_parameters par = {0};
    par.n = initial*LATTICE_SIZE-1;
    calculate_forward_rates(par.forward_rate, *beta);
    par.rho_t = rho[par.n];
    
    while (fabs(par.rho_t-par.rho_tminus) > PRECISION && par.sweep < ULONG_MAX)
    {
        for(i = 1; i <= N_SWEEPS; i++)
        {
            par.distribution[par.n]++; par.sweep++; 
            if (RAND < par.forward_rate[par.n])
            {
                par.n--;
                if (par.n == -1)
                    par.n = activate(par.distribution, par.sweep);
            }
        }
        par.rho_tminus = par.rho_t;
        par.rho_t = calculate_avg_density(par.distribution, par.sweep);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", *beta, initial, par.rho_t);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    double betas[CPUs];
    pthread_t id;
    
    initial = atof(argv[1]);
    fp = fopen("data.dat", "a");
    srand(time(0));
    for(i = 0; i < LATTICE_SIZE; i++)
        rho[i] = (i+1.0)/LATTICE_SIZE;
    for(i = 0; i < CPUs; i++)
        betas[i] = (double)i/(double)CPUs;
    
    
    //Creating threads
    for (i = 0; i < CPUs; i++) 
        pthread_create(&id, NULL, monte_carlo_sweeps, (void *)&betas[i]); 
  
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

```
````

Comment: Compacted < compactified < compactificated, I suppose :)

Comment: `for(n = 0; cumsum <= u_rand; n++) cumsum += (double)distribution[n]/(double)norm;` iterates usually once, rarely twice.  If this truly the intended functionality?.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica In simulation, particle has visited different sites `n` from `0` to `LATTICE_SIZE-1.` When particle goes to `n=-1,` which is not allowed state, so we activate it back based on its history, i.e., how much time it has visited `n.`

Comment: I am from math background, so this is what I intended -- I have box full of balls, and each ball inscribed with some number from `0` to `LATTICE_SIZE -1.` Probability of choosing any ball is equally likely. Now if I pick up ball from a `distribution,` (of number inscribed) then what is probability of it been inscribed with number `i.` I hope the `activate` is doing this. If not, then I am in trouble.

Comment: KartikChhajed  On review, my concern does not apply.  Tip: `for()` loops are best for iterating things `n` times.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Point noted, an equivalent while loop would look much nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  A run of the code through the `gcc` compiler results in:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled2.c" -o "untitled2.o" 

untitled2.c: In function ‘calculate_avg_density’:

untitled2.c:56:31: warning: conversion to ‘double’ from ‘long long unsigned int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
         avg_density += (rho[i]*distribution[i])/norm;
                               ^

untitled2.c:56:48: warning: conversion to ‘double’ from ‘long long unsigned int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
         avg_density += (rho[i]*distribution[i])/norm;
                                                ^

untitled2.c: In function ‘monte_carlo_sweeps’:

untitled2.c:65:13: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Wfloat-conversion]
     par.n = initial*LATTICE_SIZE-1;
             ^~~~~~~

untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled2.c:96:11: warning: conversion to ‘unsigned int’ from ‘time_t {aka long int}’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     srand(time(0));
           ^~~~

untitled2.c:88:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
              ^~~~

untitled2.c: In function ‘monte_carlo_sweeps’:
untitled2.c:85:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^

Compilation finished successfully.
```

The statement: `Compilation finished successfully.` only means the compiler produced some workaround for each of the warnings.  That 'workaround' may (or may not) be what you want.

regarding:

```
initial = atof(argv[1]);
```

Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the expected command line parameter was actually entered by the user.  If the expected number of command line arguments are not found, then output a `USAGE` message to `stderr`, similar to:

```
fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s initialValue\n", argv[0] );
exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
```

in function: `monte_carlo_sweeps()`

It is a bad idea to just run off the end of a non-void function and returning from a thread should be exited with:

```
pthread_exit( NULL );
```

Regarding:

```
srand(time(0));
```

This produces a compiler warning.  Suggest:

```
srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );
```

for ease of readability and understanding:

1. insert a blank line around code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default`
2. insert 2 or 3 blank lines between functions (be consistent)
3. insert an appropriate space: inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

it is best to not use 'global' variables.  Rather define them as 'local' variables within a function (like `main()` ) and pass pointers to them to sub functions that need them.

regarding:

```
#define RAND (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX
```

it is best to place parens around the whole calculation so when `RAND` is invoked all the desired order of operations is not lost.

regarding;

```
fp = fopen("data.dat", "a");
```

always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  When not successful (==NULL) then call

```
perror( "fopen to append data.dat failed" );
exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
```

where `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

regarding;

```
pthread_create(&id, NULL, monte_carlo_sweeps, (void *)&betas[i]);
```

there are going to be `CPUs` threads, each with a unique `thread_t ID`

Should always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest:

```
pthread_t id[ CPUs ];
```

and

```
if( pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, monte_carlo_sweeps, (void *)&betas[i]) != 0 )
{
    perror( "pthread_create failed" );
    // cleanup then
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

at the end of `main()`, do NOT call:

```
pthread_exit( NULL );
```

when waiting for the threads to complete.

because there are `CPUs` threads, do this instead:

```
for( int i = 0; i < CPUs; i++ )
{
    pthread_join( id[i], NULL );
}
```

Comment: There is no requirement whatsoever to call `pthread_exit()` to end a thread. Just `return`ing from the thread entry function is enough. Sure, you should return a value, even if it's just `NULL`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen,  True, there are other ways to return from a thread function other than `pthread_exit()` However, just running off the end of the function is NOT one of them

Answer (score 1):

`for(n = 0; cumsum <= u_rand; n++) cumsum += (double) distribution[n]/(double) norm;` is not clear to me that `distribution[n]` will always use a `n` in the [0... LATTICE_SIZE-1] range.  I suspect, depending on the roundings and  sequencing of adding floating point numbers, code may iterate too far and attempt  `distribution[LATTICE_SIZE]` which is bad.

Best not to risk an out of buffer access due to some rounding - even if *mathmatically*, the loop limited by  `cumsum <= u_rand` should be a sufficient end condition.

```
// for(n = 0; cumsum <= u_rand; n++)
//    cumsum += (double)distribution[n]/(double)norm;

for(n = 0; n < LATTICE_SIZE; n++) {
  cumsum += (double)distribution[n] / (double)norm;
  if (cumsum > u_rand) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not got your point. Are you saying that `n` may exceed `LATTICE_SIZE-1` is some cases due to rounding off? I see this could happen in my `for` loop. And your `for` loop takes care of it.

Comment: @KartikChhajed Yes.  The original loop's end condition is a mathematical/floating point one  and not strongly tied to `n < LATTICE_SIZE`.  I assert that original code could attempt to index beyond the array size.  By limiting the index to the valid range, that undefined behavior will not occur. If the algorithm wanted to index beyond the array, that is a problem of the algorithm.  OTOH, if it is the FP math that  caused an extra interaction, like `for (double x = 0; x < 1.0; x += 1/3.0)` iterating 4 times rather than 3, then that 4th iteration is discardable.